# Rails4 : My hstore attribute is being converted to String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, hstore

I have a Hash attribute in my model that uses Postgres hstore extention. The problem is that this attribute is converted to String by Rails4. This prevents me to make basic operations such as `.each` or `.map` to treat my hash attribute.

Using the Rails console, the Hash is not converted. Typing:

```
@device.data
@device.data.class
```

Gives in Rails console:

```
{"city"=>"London", "owner_name"=>"John"}
Hash
```

And in the application itself (using the navigator):

```
"\"city\"=>\"London\","\"owner_name\"=>\"John\"
String
```

Do you have any idea?

Update:

Here is the model:

```
class Device < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :company
  has_many :records

  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

And the corresponding migration file:

```
class CreateDevices < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :devices do |t|

      t.string :name
      t.hstore :data
      t.integer :company_id

      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :devices, :name
  end
end
```

Comment: Postgres `hstore` keep your hash like a string, this is normal behavior. Rails make [`serialization`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) when column load `hstore`

Comment: Can you post your model code.

Comment: @DickieBoy I added the model and migration file. @Зелёный But how can I use the hash in this case, like `@device.data['country']`?

Comment: Seems like your doing everything right.

Comment: What do you mean by using the navigator?

Answer (score -1):

Try deleting your tmp folder and restarting all your servers.

```
rm -rf tmp/*
```